# InternalError: (1366, u"Incorrect integer value: Select) Error

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-workbench

## Return user id from phone_number

```
GET_USER_ID = "SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE phone_number = {};"
```

I am trying to run the above query and got this error :

> InternalError: (1366, u"Incorrect integer value: 'SELECT user_id FROM
>   user WHERE phone_number = 0400001122;' for column 'user_id' at row 1")

When i run the query in the mysql workbench, it works fine and returns the correct `user_id`. I have been researching other posts as well, but most of them are insert problems and a null value for them would fix this in `INSERT` cases.

However, I am doing a `SELECT` query.

I have been struggling alot with this error, could anyhow help me out?

Comment: phonenumber type - (varchar(12)PK) user-id type - (int(11) AI PK)

Comment: read this and set your `sql-mode` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536199/1366-incorrect-integer-valuemysql

Comment: By the way, `VARCHAR(12)`  isn't big enough to hold telephone directory numbers.  Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42255754/phone-number-should-be-a-string-or-some-numeric-type-that-have-capacity-to-save/42255861#42255861

Comment: Can you share the output of this query `SHOW CREATE TABLE user `?

Comment: Could you share the snippet where this is used?

Comment: I decided to go with different way by passing user_id directly instead of querying through phone number. Not sure why it does not work the other way round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phone number value is stored in varchar field of mysql table. and it starts with 0, using any number **starts with 0 is treated as octal number** in python programming language.

kindly make changes in query and pass phone_number value as string in select query, will solve your question.

Sample query as per your input is as:

```
"SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE phone_number = '0400001122';"
```

Check this and enjoy coding :) !