# I'm trying to add a record to the database with php and mysql OOP

Tags: php, mysql

everyone, I have a hard time to understand what is going on. I'm new on OOPS and wanted to add a record to my database. I have a class customer and in that class, I have a function create() that makes a new record and insert into DB. My connection is working, I instantiate(hope that is the right term)  that function and then I call create().

```
$costumer = new Customer($args);
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$result = $costumer->create("Nome", "Cognome", 2, "email3@email.com", "12", "address", 00133, "payment", $date, "male");  

   public function create($first_name, $last_name, $phone_number, $email, $codice_fiscale, $adress, $cap, $payment, $data_of_join, $genre) {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO costumers (first_name, last_name, phone_number, email, codice_fiscale, adress, cap, payment, data_of_join, genre) 
        VALUES ('$this->first_name','$this->last_name','$this->phone_number','$this->email','$this->codice_fiscale','$this->adress','$this->cap','$this->payment','$this->data_of_join','$this->genre')";

        $result = self::$database->query($sql);

        if(!$result) {
            echo self::$database->error;
            echo self::$database->errno;
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

going to my page to see if I get any result. I have Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'phone_number' at row 11366.

My database fields are: -

```
ID
first_name
last_name
phone_number
email
codice_fiscale
adress
cap
payment
data_of_join
genre
```

Really don't know what is the problem. I made the same thing but in procedural same SQL and everything works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/2469308) related attacks. Please learn to use [Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Now, in this case, you do not need to use `$this->` to use the variables. `$this` is used when the variables are accessible class members. However, in your cases, these are function parameters.

In the current code, you can change the SQL string as follows:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO costumers (first_name, last_name, phone_number, email, codice_fiscale, adress, cap, payment, data_of_join, genre) 
        VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$phone_number','$email','$codice_fiscale','$adress','$cap','$payment','$data_of_join','$genre')";
```

Comment: Thank you so much ..... you saved my life .but why didn t throw an error becouse i was using this in a bad way ?

Comment: @AdrianLupu you need to turn on error reporting. You might have had some exception handling as well. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Answer (score 1):

This is a wild guess because you haven't told us the data types of your columns.

It looks like your phone_number column is represented in your database by an integer. You Can't Do That™. Many telephone numbers furnished by users with spaces or punctuation.

Read this: [phone number should be a string or some numeric type that have capacity to save phone number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42255754/phone-number-should-be-a-string-or-some-numeric-type-that-have-capacity-to-save/42255861#42255861)