# Migrating from Mongo to MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, mongodb, migration, database-migration

I am migrating a DB from Mongo to MySQL
the mongo DB has a column contains mobile numbers that is an array of numbers
I have exported the data in a CSV file and when I import it into a MySQL table it looks like this

```
["01151337941","01016749923"]
```

how can I modify the csv before I import so that it will look like this

```
01151337941,01016749923
```

Comment: Are the phone numbers? When you convert them to numeric values then you may lose the leading zero

Comment: have you any common pattern in terminators ?

Comment: you can also use Studio 3T  trial version and export data in sql then import in mysql.

Comment: **Telephone numbers are not integers!**  Please, please, read [this](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md).  And see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42255754/phone-number-should-be-a-string-or-some-numeric-type-that-have-capacity-to-save/42255861#42255861